# Sending SMS using AWS SNS in Ruby fails; how to get reason for failure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aws-sdk

I am trying to send a text message using AWS SNS in a Rails app. I have the gems `aws-sdk-sms` and `aws-sdk-sns` installed.

I am attempting to send the message like this:

```
Aws::SNS::Client.new(region: '[MY_REGION]', access_key_id: '[MY_KEY]', 
                     secret_access_key: '[MY_SECRET]')
                .publish(phone_number: '[MY_NUMBER]', message: 'test')
```

which returns a `Aws::SNS::Types::PublishResponse` struct with the `message_id`.

The message is not delivered and in the SNS dashboard I can see that delivery was attempted but failed.

How can I get the reason for failure?

Answer (score 0):

you have missed {} inside the publish method. due that message is not send.
Please, have a look below sample code:

```
sns = Aws::SNS::Client.new(region: ENV['AWS_SMS_REGION'], access_key_id: ENV['AWS_SMS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SMS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'])

sns.publish({phone_number: phone_number, message: message})
```

Comment: This does not answer my question, which was how to get the reason for failure, not why it was failing.

Comment: Also, it's incorrect. In the end I realized that it was failing because I was using an invalid phone number; when I fixed that, it sent successfully.